# DWORD format specifier

Tags: c++

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647458/undefined-behaviour-in-theory-and-in-practice).

Can it be that `DWORD` is **same** as `int` on some platform(How to check this?)? If that is the case, then this:

```
  DWORD v1, v2, v3, Build;
  GetVersion(&v1, &v2, &v3, &Build);
  sprintf(VersionStr, "%d.%d.%d.%d", v1, v2, v3, Build);
```

is not undefined behaviour on that platform, am I right??

Or above code is ALWAYS and everywhere UB?

How to check whether `DWORD` is same as `int` on that platform?

(because maybe I am thinking on that computer where this code is run above is not undefined behaviour)

Comment: I have found this piece of code in my Visual Studio 2013 environment in Windows 7:
`typedef unsigned long       DWORD;`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: So my code is ALWAYS UB?

Comment: @BoPersson: So my code is ALWAYS UB?

Comment: "How to check this?" Make sure the relevant compiler warnings are all on. Clang, for example, will warn if the arguments to a `printf` don't match the ones in the format string.

Comment: @Jongware: I meant how to double check DWORD is not int

Comment: It's never *just* `int`. It could be `unsigned long`, it could be `unsigned int`, the important thing here is that it's *always* `unsigned` and always 32-bits.

Comment: And I suggest having your compiler check it.

Comment: Yes it's undefined behavior to use the wrong format, even for such simple things as `signed` versus `unsigned`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5851524/440558

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Even for those unsigned values which can fit in int?

Comment: Btw, I think it is coming close to an MSVC implementation  defect that these ubiquitously used type definitions do not come with corresponding format definitions/macros. (Or did I miss them when I browsed the MSDN?) My guess is that, apart from originally targeting 16 bit Intel CPUs and not thinking ahead much, everybody was also less paranoid 20 years ago than today -- partly because there were fewer reasons to be paranoid because the compilers were simpler.

Comment: @BoPersson “`DWORD` is … always unsigned” — Always? `using DWORD = signed char*[2]; // double word`.

Answer (score 5):

On a 32 bit compiler, the format specifier which you can use to print the value of DWORD is `%lu`. You can also use `%ld` if you want to print the value in decimal format.

You can also refer a thread: [Why in C++ do we use DWORD rather than unsigned int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995251/why-in-c-do-we-use-dword-rather-than-unsigned-int)

Comment: Depends on compiler and target platform. Using GCC and targeting a 64-bit system, `long` is 64 bits, while `DWORD` is still 32 bits.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg:- Yes thats correct, it will depend on the compiler.

Comment: So we can shout back at OP: "no, it is not **ALWAYS** UB". More like, "it depends" :)

Comment: @Jongware:why it depends if it is always unsigned it is always UB, no?

Comment: So why not just `%u` or `%d`?